# Android: how do i parse this mixed up json response

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, object

The only thing that's guaranteed to always be there is the messagesByDate obj.
The array and objects named such as "15 MAY 2012" are generated by a server(no control) based on rather or not messages are present for that date.

If u notice the first date represented is an array while the other dates are objects containing other objects that have been numbered.

QUESTION 1: how do i parse this without knowing what dates will be present?

QUESTION 2: Some messages are in an array instead of an object. how do I put them all together in one ArrayList. Rather its in an array or not because the array will not always been there.

Please any help would be appreciated as I'm down to my last hair

Thanks.

```
{
"messagesByDate":{
  "15 May 2012":[
     {
        "id":"1383483367",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"4318264",
        "message":"ok will do",
        "date_sent":"1337133515",
        "date_sent_ago":"7 mins ago"
     },
     {
        "id":"1380222533",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"5159567",
        "message":"ok well hmu",
        "date_sent":"1337085122",
        "date_sent_ago":"13 hrs ago"
     },
     {
        "id":"1380172978",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"5159567",
        "message":"superhead",
        "date_sent":"1337083910",
        "date_sent_ago":"13 hrs ago"
     },
     {
        "id":"1380130860",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"5159567",
        "message":"you ready B",
        "date_sent":"1337082797",
        "date_sent_ago":"14 hrs ago"
     },
     {
        "id":"1378841432",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"5159567",
        "message":"hit my cell tho",
        "date_sent":"1337054524",
        "date_sent_ago":"22 hrs ago"
     },
     {
        "id":"1378836763",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"5159567",
        "message":"whats up baby",
        "date_sent":"1337054475",
        "date_sent_ago":"22 hrs ago"
     }
  ],
  "12 May 2012":{
     "6":{
        "id":"1362948558",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"4318264",
        "message":"ok ima text u",
        "date_sent":"1336819668",
        "date_sent_ago":"3 days ago"
     }
  },
  "11 May 2012":{
     "7":{
        "id":"1361356267",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"5159567",
        "message":"yea thats cool",
        "date_sent":"1336790738",
        "date_sent_ago":"3 days ago"
     },
     "8":{
        "id":"1357783913",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"5159567",
        "message":"sorry im here. would u like to exchange numebers instead?",
        "date_sent":"1336722533",
        "date_sent_ago":"4 days ago"
     },
     "9":{
        "id":"1357759262",
        "conversation_id":"274618561",
        "user_id":"5159567",
        "message":"hello?",
        "date_sent":"1336721851",
        "date_sent_ago":"4 days ago"
     }
     }
   }
}
```

THE ANSWER SORTA-KINDA

```
JSONObject dateHolder = r.getJSONObject("messagesByDate");
    Iterator holderItr = dateHolder.keys();


    while(holderItr.hasNext()){


        String thisdate = holderItr.next().toString();
        Object date = dateHolder.get(thisdate);


        if (date instanceof JSONArray) {
            System.out.println(thisdate+" is an ARRAY.");
            JSONArray jarray = (JSONArray) date;
            for(int x=0;x<jarray.length();x++){
                String msgId = jarray.getJSONObject(x).getString("id");
                String msgConvoId = jarray.getJSONObject(x).getString("conversation_id");
                String msgUserId = jarray.getJSONObject(x).getString("user_id");
                String msgBody = jarray.getJSONObject(x).getString("message");
                String msgDateSent = jarray.getJSONObject(x).getString("date_sent");
                String msgDateSentAgo = jarray.getJSONObject(x).getString("date_sent_ago");
                HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
                temp.put("msgId",msgId);
                temp.put("msgUserId", msgUserId);
                temp.put("msgBody", msgBody);
                temp.put("msgDateSent", msgDateSent);
                temp.put("msgDateSentAgo", msgDateSentAgo);
                messages.add(temp);

            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(thisdate+" is an OBJECT.");
            JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) date;
            Iterator insideDate = jobj.keys();
            while(insideDate.hasNext()){
                String number = insideDate.next().toString();
                System.out.println(number);
                String msgId = jobj.getJSONObject(number).getString("id");
                String msgConvoId = jobj.getJSONObject(number).getString("conversation_id");

                String msgUserId =jobj.getJSONObject(number).getString("user_id");

                String msgBody = jobj.getJSONObject(number).getString("message");

                String msgDateSent = jobj.getJSONObject(number).getString("date_sent");

                String msgDateSentAgo = jobj.getJSONObject(number).getString("date_sent_ago");
                HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
                temp.put("msgId",msgId);
                temp.put("msgUserId", msgUserId);
                temp.put("msgBody", msgBody);
                temp.put("msgDateSent", msgDateSent);
                temp.put("msgDateSentAgo", msgDateSentAgo);
                messages.add(temp);

            }
        }
    }
```

This gives me all the messages in a HashMap and adds it to an ArrayList called messages like I want but its out of order by date. the json is listed by date...anyone know if there is a way to direct json reading? OR are my WHILE and FOR loops out of order? can i sort hashmaps by a key? I'll google that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject json = service.getJunk();
JSONObject msgJson = json.getJSONObject("messagesByDate");
for( Iterator it = msgJson.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Object obj = msgJson.get( (String)it.next() );
    if( obj instanceof JSONObject ) {
       JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)obj;
       // process json object
    } else {
       JSONArray arry = (JSONArray)obj;
       // process array
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse tells me that the for statement must use a variable or an instance of iterable for msgJson.keys()

Comment: It's pretty easy to convert it to use old style iteration in Java.  I updated the code this time.  Bear in mind I'm just doing this off the top of my head.  I'm not testing it so trivial syntax changes like this is something the reader should be able to do on their own.

Comment: Yea I started playing around with Iterator next() and hasNext() last night instead of the FOR statement and got pretty close. but not the two combined so i'll try that. I think the important part i was missing was to simply test if its an 'instanceof'. Im goin to look over and test this example and see if I can get it to work. Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 1):

First create a class like this:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import android.util.Log;

public class Message{

    private LinkedList<String> id              = new LinkedList<String>();
    private LinkedList<String> conversation_id = new LinkedList<String>();
    private LinkedList<String> user_id     = new LinkedList<String>();
    private LinkedList<String> message     = new LinkedList<String>();
    private LinkedList<String> date_sent       = new LinkedList<String>();
    private LinkedList<String> date_sent_ago   = new LinkedList<String>();

    public LinkedList<String> getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id.add(id);
    }

.
.
.
    // For checking response after you get info from server
    public void printContent() {
        for(String str : id)
            Log.i("Id>>>", str);
.
.
.
    }

}
```

Then you need to call server in onCreate() add this code:

```
 if(Manager.isOnline(this)) // Check Internet connection and if you find it then
            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Now, you should add this class:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "MyAsyncTask is about to start...");
            showProgressBar();
        }


        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            boolean status = false; 

            // Get News items in json format
            msg = getMessageItems(); // msg is an instance of Message class define it as global variable.
            msg.printContent(); // Check result in logcat

            if(msg != null)
                status = true;

            return status;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "MyAsyncTask finished its task. Data returned to caller.");

            if(result)
                displayData();

            hideProgressBar();
        }
    }
```

Here we will connect to server, get Json data and parse it.

```
private Menu getMenuItems() {
    Message mMessage = new Message ();
    String response = null;
    String connection = **YOUR_URL**;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(connection);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.i(TAG, "Try to open: " + connection);
        Log.i(TAG, "Response code is: " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            if (in != null) {
                StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                // Read character by character              
                int ch = 0;
                while ((ch = in.read()) != -1)
                    strBuilder.append((char) ch);

                // get returned message and show it
                response = strBuilder.toString();
                Log.i("JSON returned by server:", response);

                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray contestantObjects = jObject.getJSONArray("**messagesByDate**");
                for(int i=0; i<contestantObjects.length(); i++){
                    mMessage .setId(contestantObjects.getJSONObject(i).getString("id").toString());
// Repeat this to get all of other items
                }
            }

            in.close();

        } else
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't open connection in getMenuItems()");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mMessage;
}
```

Now you have an object that each of its item is a list. You can do whatever you want in display method. you can pass it as an object to adapter to show its data.

```
private void displayData() {
        messageAdapter.setData(msg);
        listView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: This sample SEEMS to be on track with what I want in the end(a list of data for an adapter). But it will take a while for me to wrap my head around all parts of this sample and I'm afraid it might produce more problems aside from the ones at hand. BUT I WILL DEF try it cause I been wanting to play with asyctasks. Thanks again.